# 'table_structor': Could not find table 'views'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-admin

I'm trying to use rails_admin for the first time and I'm getting the following error during installation:

```
'table_structor': Could not find table 'views'
```

I've never had a model named 'views', so I'm not even sure why it's looking for this. Any ideas what may be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your models folder. You probably have a rouge model you aren't using.